# is it possible to set the windows login icon to match active directory photo?

Tags: windows-7, active-directory, avatar-generation

Pretty much right there in the title. We are going to be placing employee photos into active directory. What we also want to do is use that photo as the login avatar for windows. Is there a straight forward way to do sync the two or does it have to be a script that is run any time the photo is changed?

Comment: You may want to also try this question on ServerFault and Superuser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any in-box solution. You'd have to come up with some sort of scripted solution - perhaps on logon.

I'd think about your risk here though - is copying employee photos to laptops, for example, a good idea?

Comment: its what the boss wants. we figured out the logon script. we're just gonna go that route.